# Transformations of Linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra

I tried out a problem as done in the text, yet I do not understand how they arrived at the solution.
It goes as follows:

Example 2.6
For $a \in \mathbb R$, we seek all solutions of the following system of equations:
\begin{cases}  
-2x1 + 4x2 - 2x3 - x4 + 4x5 = -3\\
4x1 - 8x2 + 3x3 - 3x4 + x5 = 2\\
x1 - 2x2 + x3 - x4 + x5 = 0 \\
x1 - 2x2      - 3x4 + 4x5 = a  \end{cases}

I will proceed to explain their solution (before I explain what confuses me)
The text book solution:
[The text book solution is attached in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7Edu.png)

My queries:

1. When they were getting it into row echelon format, how did the RHS row  suddenly become
   a+1
2. How did the particular solution become
   $\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 0\\-1 \\ 1\\0\end{bmatrix}$
3. How did they get the other two matrices in the general solution (at the bottom of the image).
   They have written
   $x=\begin{bmatrix}2 \\0 \\-1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}+\lambda_1\begin{bmatrix}2 \\1 \\0 \\0 \\0\end{bmatrix}+\lambda_2\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 0\\ -1\\2 \\1\end{bmatrix}$

I had tried solving it myself. I got stuck at the question 2, so I wasn't able to get to figure out how query#3 is done.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know how good it is to write the entire statement in bold, but it's not easy on the eyes. Consider better writing your post and fixing MathJax, avoid using images.

Comment: To make subscripts in LaTeX, use the character _  -- so x_1 will render as $x_1$, etc.

Comment: Have you read earlier in the textbook where it describes the general process of how to find the general form of the solution once you've reduced the system to RREF?

Comment: I'll just put in a comment that others can expand on. (1) In the process of row echelon, they did a $R_4\to R_4-R_2-R_3$, that's how they got the $a-2-(-3)=a+1$. (2) In the final equations, try putting $x_5=0$ and solving, and then when you get a equation in just $x_1$ and $x_2$, put $x_2=0$. That should give you a particular solution (in fact the one they mention pops out). (3) They found out 2 other particular solutions such that all 3 were linearly independent, and glued them together (hope you can fill in the gaps!).

Answer (score 1):

1. The line where is written "$...|a]-R_2-R_3$" provides $a-2+3=a+1$;
2. They get the particular solution with $x_5=0$ and $x_2=0$;
3. By considering $x_2$ and $x_5$ as parameters noted respectively $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, we obtain $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)=(2+2x_2+2x_5,x_2,-1-x_5,1+2x_5,x_5)=(2,0,-1,1,0)+x_2(2,1,0,0,0)+x_5(2,0,-1,2,1)$, which provides the general solution.
   (hope this helps)